# function with multiple arguments in PHP

Tags: php, optional-arguments

I'm starting to learn oop in php and i would like to know whats wrong with my method that accepts multiple arguments.

```
class Database
{    
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        if($method == 'insertData') 
        {
            if(count($args) == 2)
            {
                return call_user_func_array(($this, 'insertData1'), $args)); //unexpected token ',' after $this
            }
            else if(count($args) == 3)
            {
                return call_user_func_array(($this, 'insertData2'), $args));   
            }
        }
    }

    public function insertData1($table, $field1)
    {

    }

    public function insertData2($table, $field1, $field2)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a trivial to fix syntax error. `($this, 'insertData1')` is not a [valid callback notation](http://de1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Comment: Isn't call only triggered on inaccessible methods, and so wouldn't even be called in this case, as both methods are public?

Comment: @JackieXu the OP is apparently calling `insertData` only.

Comment: You shouldn't use these magic functions in your code, especially when you are still learning OOP. Make functions explicit. Do call them explicitly. Avoid any magic functions - they make your code incomprehensible - and most editors cannot offer autocompletion anymore. Or in short: Code a `function insertData($table, array $fields)` and pass it an array of fields - now you can pass as many fields as you want, without having to code a function for every case.

Comment: yes @Gordon it was the a syntax error with the callback function, not a problem with the logic itself

Comment: @Sven, thats exactly what i wanted . And thanks for the brief explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing array from your method call:

```
call_user_func_array(array($this, 'insertData1'), $args);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `call_user_func_array` must be a callable or, in your case, an array:

```
call_user_func_array(array($this, 'insertData1'), $args));
```

instead of:

```
call_user_func_array(($this, 'insertData1'), $args));
```